# Using comma-formatted numbers for DecimalField in Wagtail page admin

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a request from a client to have page admin fields that they can add/read numbers into  with commas such as 1,000,000.

The Django model field to store the value would be a `django.db.models.fields.DecimalField` instance.

From looking at the Django docs, this is something that’s supported by the `django.forms.fields.DecimalField` `localized` property, but I can’t find a way of enforcing it in the Wagtail admin, even when subclassing the Wagtail `BaseFieldPanel` `__init__` function with `self.bound_field.field.localize = True`.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the fields that Wagtail FieldPanel uses by customising generated forms documented here:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms.WagtailAdminPageForm

Basic example below - `myapp/models.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models

from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page

class MyCustomPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
    # fields here are django.forms fields
    # when set to localize, renders as a TextInput widget
    total_amount = forms.DecimalField(localize=True)

    # when left with defaults, renders as a NumberInput widget
    # total_amount = forms.DecimalField()

    # can also set any kind of widget here
    # total_amount = forms.DecimalField(widget=MyCustomDecimalWidget)

class MyCustomPage(Page):
    # fields here are django.db.models fields
    total_amount = models.DecimalField()
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('total_amount'),
    ]
    base_form_class = MyCustomPageForm # important: must set this
```

When you set the form field to `localize=True` it appears to follow the intended behaviour as per the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield) which is to render a TextInput widget.

You could also set your own widget for any field in your page's form class if you want to do some more complicated functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @lb-ben-johnston - also to the Wagtail team who pointed me in a similar direction.

I have it working now in a loosely coupled fashion with this:

```
from django.forms.fields import DecimalField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm


class ProductPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductPageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key, field in self.fields.items():
            if isinstance(field, DecimalField):
                field.localize = True
                field.widget.is_localized = True


# The Page class to localize

class LocalizedPage(Page):

    base_form_class = ProductPageForm

    # Rest of page class
```

Make sure you explictly pass a `TextInput` widget to the field handler:

```
FieldPanel('localized_field', widget=TextInput)
```

Finally, make sure that the thousand separator flag is explicitly set in your `settings.py` or `base.py`:

```
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
```